# RGraph - How to make this line graph update correctly and be side scrolling

Tags: javascript, ajax, rgraph

I am trying to get a dynamically updating side scrolling line graph to work in rgraph. It updates once every second via an ajax call to a php script that outputs data in this format:

```
  {"cpu":28.43,"mem":75.01,"rx":0,"timestamp":1471535457240}
```

Right now with the following code I am just trying to get it to work with the CPU data only. The ajax calls are working once a second but I cant get the graph to update. The data is pre-populated with for loop.

What am I doing wrong?

```
     var cpu = [], mem = [], rx = [], timestamp = [];
    var dataset;
    var totalPoints = 100;
    var updateInterval = 1000;
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var canvas    = document.getElementById("cvs");
    var temp = [];

    // Make and draw the chart
    var line = new RGraph.Line({
        id: 'cvs',
        data: cpu,
        options: {
            ymax: 100,
            backgroundGridAutofitNumvlines: 10,
            backgroundGridVlines: true,
            backgroundGridBorder: true,
            numxticks: 10,
            tickmarks: true,
            noaxes: false,
            textSize: 12,
            gutterLeft: 50,
            textColor: '#aaa',
            scaleZerostart: true,
            textAccessible: true
        }
    }).draw();


    function initData() {
        now -= totalPoints * updateInterval;
        for (var i = 0; i < totalPoints; i++) {
           // temp = [now += updateInterval, 0];
            cpu[i] = 0;
        }
    }



    function GetData() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        $.ajax({
            url: "server_load.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (_data) {
                drawGraph(_data);
            },
            error: function () {
                setTimeout(GetData, updateInterval);
            }
        });
    }




    function drawGraph(_data) {

        console.log(cpu);
        cpu.shift();
        var Now = _data['timestamp'];

        temp = [Now, _data.cpu];
        cpu.push(temp);

        console.log(temp[1]);

        // Reset the canvas
        line.reset(document.getElementById('cvs'));

        line.original_data[0] = temp[1];
        line.draw();


        setTimeout(GetData, updateInterval);
    }



    window.onload = function ()
    {
        initData();
        GetData();
    };
```

Here is my php script that works on my local Ubuntu machine:

```
   class serverLoad {

const OS_LINUX = "Linux";
const OS_FREEBSD = "FreeBSD";
const OS_OSX = "Darwin";
const PATH_NETSTAT = "/usr/sbin/netstat";

public $cpuLoad;
public $memoryUsed;
public $timeStamp;
public $networkBandwidth;
public $interface = 'eth0';
protected $sampleSleep = 1000000;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->generateData();
}

/**
 *
 */

public function generateData(){

    $this->cpuLoad = $this->getServerLoad();
    $this->memoryUsed = $this->getSystemMemoryInfo();
    $this->networkBandwidth = $this->getNetworkBandwidth();
    $this->timeStamp = $this->msTimeStamp();


    $totalMemory = $this->memoryUsed['MemTotal'];
    $freeMemory = $this->memoryUsed['MemTotal'] - $this->memoryUsed['MemFree'] - $this->memoryUsed['Buffers'] - $this->memoryUsed['Cached'];
    $MemoryPercentage =  round(($freeMemory/$totalMemory) * 100, 2) ;

    $results = array('cpu' => $this->cpuLoad, 'mem' => $MemoryPercentage, 'rx' => $this->networkBandwidth['rx'], 'timestamp' => $this->timeStamp);

    echo json_encode($results);
}

/**
 *  Returns server load in percent (just number, without percent sign)
 */

protected function getServerLoad()
{
    $load = null;

    if (stristr(PHP_OS, "win"))
    {
        $cmd = "wmic cpu get loadpercentage /all";
        @exec($cmd, $output);

        if ($output)
        {
            foreach ($output as $line)
            {
                if ($line && preg_match("/^[0-9]+\$/", $line))
                {
                    $load = $line;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (is_readable("/proc/stat"))
        {
            // Collect 2 samples - each with 1 second period
            // See: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load#Der_Load_Average_auf_Unix-Systemen
            $statData1 = $this->_getServerLoadLinuxData();
            usleep($this->sampleSleep);
            $statData2 = $this->_getServerLoadLinuxData();

            if
            (
                (!is_null($statData1)) &&
                (!is_null($statData2))
            )
            {
                // Get difference
                $statData2[0] -= $statData1[0];
                $statData2[1] -= $statData1[1];
                $statData2[2] -= $statData1[2];
                $statData2[3] -= $statData1[3];

                // Sum up the 4 values for User, Nice, System and Idle and calculate
                // the percentage of idle time (which is part of the 4 values!)
                $cpuTime = $statData2[0] + $statData2[1] + $statData2[2] + $statData2[3];

                // Invert percentage to get CPU time, not idle time
                $load = 100 - ($statData2[3] * 100 / $cpuTime);
            }
        }
    }

    return round($load, 2);
}

/**
 *  Used to get the server load on linux machines
 */

protected function _getServerLoadLinuxData()
{
    if (is_readable("/proc/stat"))
    {
        $stats = @file_get_contents("/proc/stat");

        if ($stats !== false)
        {
            // Remove double spaces to make it easier to extract values with explode()
            $stats = preg_replace("/[[:blank:]]+/", " ", $stats);

            // Separate lines
            $stats = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n\r", "\r"), "\n", $stats);
            $stats = explode("\n", $stats);

            // Separate values and find line for main CPU load
            foreach ($stats as $statLine)
            {
                $statLineData = explode(" ", trim($statLine));

                // Found!
                if
                (
                    (count($statLineData) >= 5) &&
                    ($statLineData[0] == "cpu")
                )
                {
                    return array(
                        $statLineData[1],
                        $statLineData[2],
                        $statLineData[3],
                        $statLineData[4],
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}


protected function wmiWBemLocatorQuery( $query ) {
    if ( class_exists( '\\COM' ) ) {
        try {
            $WbemLocator = new \COM( "WbemScripting.SWbemLocator" );
            $WbemServices = $WbemLocator->ConnectServer( '127.0.0.1', 'root\CIMV2' );
            $WbemServices->Security_->ImpersonationLevel = 3;
            // use wbemtest tool to query all classes for namespace root\cimv2
            return $WbemServices->ExecQuery( $query );
        } catch ( \com_exception $e ) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    } elseif ( ! extension_loaded( 'com_dotnet' ) )
        trigger_error( 'It seems that the COM is not enabled in your php.ini', E_USER_WARNING );
    else {
        $err = error_get_last();
        trigger_error( $err['message'], E_USER_WARNING );
    }

    return false;
}

// _dir_in_allowed_path this is your function to detect if a file is withing the allowed path (see the open_basedir PHP directive)
protected function getSystemMemoryInfo( $output_key = '' ) {
    $keys = array( 'MemTotal', 'MemFree', 'MemAvailable', 'SwapTotal', 'SwapFree', 'Buffers', 'Cached' );
    $result = array();
    $isWin = false;

    try {
        // LINUX
        if ( !$isWin ) {
            $proc_dir = '/proc/';
            $data =  @file( $proc_dir . 'meminfo' );
            if ( is_array( $data ) )
                foreach ( $data as $d ) {
                    if ( 0 == strlen( trim( $d ) ) )
                        continue;
                    $d = preg_split( '/:/', $d );
                    $key = trim( $d[0] );
                    if ( ! in_array( $key, $keys ) )
                        continue;
                    $value = 1000 * floatval( trim( str_replace( ' kB', '', $d[1] ) ) );
                    $result[$key] = $value;
                }
        } else      // WINDOWS
        {
            $wmi_found = false;
            if ( $wmi_query = wmiWBemLocatorQuery(
                "SELECT FreePhysicalMemory,FreeVirtualMemory,TotalSwapSpaceSize,TotalVirtualMemorySize,TotalVisibleMemorySize FROM Win32_OperatingSystem" ) ) {
                foreach ( $wmi_query as $r ) { // TODO add Buffers and cached to this loop
                    $result['MemFree'] = $r->FreePhysicalMemory * 1024;
                    $result['MemAvailable'] = $r->FreeVirtualMemory * 1024;
                    $result['SwapFree'] = $r->TotalSwapSpaceSize * 1024;
                    $result['SwapTotal'] = $r->TotalVirtualMemorySize * 1024;
                    $result['MemTotal'] = $r->TotalVisibleMemorySize * 1024;
                    $wmi_found = true;
                }
            }
            // TODO a backup implementation using the $_SERVER array
        }
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    return empty( $output_key ) || ! isset( $result[$output_key] ) ? $result : $result[$output_key];
}


 /**
  *  Returns network bandwidth usage
  */
protected function getNetworkBandwidth(){

    $rx[] = $this->getInterfaceReceivedBytes($this->interface);
    $tx[] = $this->getInterfaceSentBytes($this->interface);
    usleep($this->sampleSleep);
    $rx[] = $this->getInterfaceReceivedBytes($this->interface);
    $tx[] = $this->getInterfaceSentBytes($this->interface);

    $tbps = $tx[1] - $tx[0];
    $rbps = $rx[1] - $rx[0];
    //convert to kbps
    $bandwidth['rx'] = round(($rbps * 8) / 1000, 2);
    $bandwidth['tx'] = round(($tbps * 8) / 1000, 2);

    return $bandwidth;
}


protected function getInterfaceReceivedBytes($interface)
{
    if ($this->isLinux()) {
        $filepath = '/sys/class/net/%s/statistics/rx_bytes';
        $output = file_get_contents(sprintf($filepath, $interface));

        return $output;
    }

    if ($this->isFreeBSD() || $this->isOSX()) {
        $command = "%s -ibn| grep %s | grep Link | awk '{print $7}'";
        exec(sprintf($command, PATH_NETSTAT, $interface), $output);

        return array_shift($output);
    }

    throw new Exception('Unable to guess OS');
}

protected function getInterfaceSentBytes($interface)
{
    if ($this->isLinux()) {
        $filepath = '/sys/class/net/%s/statistics/tx_bytes';
        $output = file_get_contents(sprintf($filepath, $interface));

        return $output;
    }

    if ($this->isFreeBSD() || $this->isOSX()) {
        $command = "%s -ibn| grep %s | grep Link | awk '{print $10}'";
        exec(sprintf($command, PATH_NETSTAT, $interface), $output);

        return array_shift($output);
    }

    throw new Exception('Unable to guess OS');
}


protected function isOSX()
{
    $uname = explode(' ', php_uname());
    return $uname[0] === self::OS_OSX;
}

protected function isLinux()
{
    $uname = explode(' ', php_uname());
    return $uname[0] === self::OS_LINUX;
}

protected function isFreeBSD()
{
    $uname = explode(' ', php_uname());
    return $uname[0] === self::OS_FREEBSD;
}


/**
*  Returns current unix timestamp
*/
protected function msTimeStamp() {
    return round(microtime(1) * 1000);
}


 }

 $data = new serverLoad();
```

I have also setup a jsfiddle but not sure how to get it working with the ajax call:   http://fiddle.jshell.net/Vbgkk/18/